# How to send http request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, opencart

```
session.post(
    'http://myopencart.example.com/index.php?route=api/cart/add',
    params={'api_token':'768ef1810185cd6562478f61d2'},
    data={
        'product_id':'100'
        'quantuty':'1'
    }
)
```

How to I post this in flutter. In this api there is two type of data to be posted.

I need solution for this I didn't tried yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send HTTP requests in Flutter you can use one of the many packages available. Some examples:

- [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)
- [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)
- [chopper](https://pub.dev/packages/chopper)

#### Example with `http` package

You first need to [add the package to the dependencies](https://pub.dev/packages/http/install):

```
flutter pub add http
```

You can then use `http.post()` method to send an HTTP request.

**NB**: the only required function field is the *URL*, and must be provided as first parameter, while the others are not strictly needed. Also notice that all the parameters of the HTTP request are provided inside the body, since it's a *POST* request.

Example function:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<String> sendPOST() async {
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('http://myopencart.example.com/index.php?route=api/cart/add'),
        // NB: you don't need to fill headers field
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' // 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or whatever you need
        },
        body: {
            'api_token': '768ef1810185cd6562478f61d2',
            'product_id': '100',
            'quantity': '1',
        },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.body;
    } else {
        return "Error ${response.statusCode}: ${response.body}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


final response = await http.post(
Uri.parse('http://myopencart.example.com/index.php?route=api/cart/add'),
body: {
  'api_token': '768ef1810185cd6562478f61d2',
  'product_id': '100',
  'quantity': '1', // Corrected the typo in 'quantity'
 },
 );

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
// Request was successful, you can handle the response here
print('Response: ${response.body}');
} else {
// Request failed
print('Failed with status code: ${response.statusCode}');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

First, let's analyze the api requested parameters:

- http://myopencart.example.com/index.php?route=api/cart/add is the url
- 'api_token':'768ef1810185cd6562478f61d2' should be put in header
- {
  'product_id':'100'
  'quantuty':'1'
  } are arguments which will be in the boday

Here is how you can perform the request using [Http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

```
var url = Uri.parse(
      'http://myopencart.example.com/index.php?route=api/cart/add');

  var data = {
    'product_id': '100',
    'quantity': '1',
  };

  // Send the data as a JSON-encoded body
  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'api_token': '768ef1810185cd6562478f61d2',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(data),
  );
```